# How to deserialize my jSON string array to obtain my Username?

Tags: php, json, xamarin.forms, json-deserialization

As you can see in my PHP script I wrote a query to get all user data from a specific user (when logged in) by using the unique Id. When I got my JSON string i want only the username. This username I would like to display on the screen of my emulator:

**PHP-code** (don't worry about SQL injection --> I'll fix it later)

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

$Id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Id']);

$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from User WHERE Id = '$Id'");

$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) 
{
    $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

**Xamarin-Code**
So I would like to deserialize ONLY the username of the json string and after to display it on the emulator screen. Could someone help me with the deserialization of the Username-object? In this code, 'List' and 'res' are red underlined...

```
    public async void GetUserData()
    {
        user u = new user();

        HttpResponseMessage res;

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Id", u.Id)
        });

        res = await client.PostAsync("http://10.0.2.2/DATA/USER/DataByID/Data.php", content);

        var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(res); // 'res' and '<List>' are underlined

        u.Username = users[1]; // I want to refer to the second property in the json string (Username)

        BindingContext = u; // displaying the Username on the screen of the emulator
    }
```

**JSON - String**

```
[{"Id":"13","Username":"aze","Email":"aze@aze.be","Passwd":"0a5b3913cbc9a9092311630e869b4442","Age":"27"}]
```

Comment: Why do you `SELECT *` if you only want `Username`?

Comment: Also, why loop if only one row?

Comment: Because my goal is to work with all the data of my user but just for this example i just need my username

Comment: Yes i know, is this that worse? Has this an impact on the deserilazation?

Comment: I don't know anything about xamarin.forms but `$rows[] = $r;` creates an additional dimension in the array that you may not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<user>>(json);
u = users[0];
// u will now contain all of your user properties
BindingContext = u;
```

Comment: When using this code i obtain following error (breakmode): "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'"

Comment: then your deserialization is not working.  Does your `user` C# class match your json?  Use json2csharp.com to check

Comment: I've checked it and the user class is identical with the output of the site u send. I think it's maybe because our Id in the MySQL database is 'INT' and in our Xamarin it is 'STRING'

Comment: I just tested this deserialization and it worked for me

Comment: Can you show me what you did or show your code plz? But when we put the json string into the site you sent we obtain the same class as we have in xamarin so that is not hte problem...

Comment: it's exactly what I posted in my answer

Comment: I'm a bit confused because you don't even use a php script implementation?